# Error because of SQL syntax

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a form that uploads images to a server and another file that retrieves the image from the database.

**Error:**

> error in INSERT into 'images_tbl' ('images_path','submission_date') VALUES ('images/04-01-2015-1420392279.png','2015-01-04') == You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''images_tbl' ('images_path','submission_date') VALUES ('images/04-01-2015-14' at line 1

**index.php:**

```
<form action="saveimage.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">

<table style="border-collapse: collapse; font: 12px Tahoma;" border="1" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
<tbody><tr>
<td>
<input name="uploadedimage" type="file">
</td>

</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<input name="Upload Now" type="submit" value="Upload Image">
</td>
</tr>

</tbody></table>

</form>
```

**index2.php:**

```
<?php
include("mysqlconnect.php");

$select_query = "SELECT 'images_path' FROM  'images_tbl' ORDER by 'images_id' DESC";
$sql = mysql_query($select_query) or die(mysql_error());    
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql,MYSQL_BOTH)){

?>

<table style="border-collapse: collapse; font: 12px Tahoma;" border="1" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
<tbody><tr>
<td>

<img src="<?php echo $row[" images_path"];="" ?="">" alt="" />">

</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>

<?php
}
?>
```

**mysqlconnect.php:**

```
<?php
/**********MYSQL Settings****************/
$host="localhost";
$databasename="karma";
$user="root";
$pass="";
/**********MYSQL Settings****************/

$conn=mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);

if($conn)
{
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($databasename, $conn);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
}
}
else
{
    die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}
?>
```

**saveimage.php:**

```
<?php
include("mysqlconnect.php");

    function GetImageExtension($imagetype)
     {
       if(empty($imagetype)) return false;
       switch($imagetype)
       {
           case 'image/bmp': return '.bmp';
           case 'image/gif': return '.gif';
           case 'image/jpeg': return '.jpg';
           case 'image/png': return '.png';
           default: return false;
       }
     }

if (!empty($_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"])) {

    $file_name=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"];
    $temp_name=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["tmp_name"];
    $imgtype=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["type"];
    $ext= GetImageExtension($imgtype);
    $imagename=date("d-m-Y")."-".time().$ext;
    $target_path = "images/".$imagename;

if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $target_path)) {

    $query_upload="INSERT into 'images_tbl' ('images_path','submission_date') VALUES 

('".$target_path."','".date("Y-m-d")."')";
    mysql_query($query_upload) or die("error in $query_upload == ".mysql_error());  

}else{

   exit("Error While uploading image on the server");
} 

}

?>;
```

**SQL:**

```
CREATE TABLE images_tbl(
   images_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   images_path VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
   submission_date DATE,
   PRIMARY KEY (images_id)
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `single quotes` from `table name` and `column list`.

```
INSERT into images_tbl (images_path,submission_date) 
         VALUES ('images/04-01-2015-1420392279.png','2015-01-04')
```

If `object` names are like `keywords` then use `backticks` not `single quotes`

Comment: @Krill - So is it working now

Comment: But now i get a semicolon after clicking the upload button

Comment: @Krill - **Be clear,** where you get that semicolon. Are you getting any error.

Comment: No i am not getting any error

Comment: @Krill - Whether data got inserted into `images_tbl` table

Comment: After i select my image and click upload button i move to a next page where it shows a ; only

Comment: yes the data is getting inserted

Comment: @Krill - That's a different question dude and i have no idea about it. According to the problem stated in question, problem is solved right

Answer (score 1):

Don't put 'images_tbl' and column names between quotes: the correct query should be

```
$query_upload="INSERT into images_tbl (images_path,submission_date) VALUES ('images/04-01-2015-1420392279.png','2015-01-04')
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have confused **back-ticks** with **single quotes** ,

You should wrap your MySQL Object names in a back-tick ` not in a single quote '

```
INSERT into `images_tbl` (`images_path`,`submission_date`) 
VALUES ('images/04-01-2015-1420392279.png','2015-01-04')
```